How to use Chewy :sidekiq strategy?
I’m using Chewy (version 7.6.0) in my Ruby on Rails project and have encountered an issue. I’ve also reported it on GitHub.
I have four indexes configured in my project. The indexing runs fine with :atomic.
However, when I set the strategy to :sidekiq, I encounter the following error in all my jobs that are created by Chewy:
NoMethodError: undefined method `dig' for "UsersIndex":String

Is there a workaround or a solution to resolve this error?
